# Automatically writing combined scatterplots and histograms to a folder

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe which contains original and transformed variables that need to be plotted in an image that I export to folder. The image contains a scatterplot of the data and two individual histograms. I have not been able to create a loop or find a function which can automate this procedure.

Below is a practice dataset that I am using as well as the manual procedure that I am using to create the figures.

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = 1:16)
df$Var_A <- c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31)
df$Var_B <- c(10,0,0,0,12,12,12,12,0,14,NA_real_,14,16,16,16,16)
df$Var_C <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16)
df$Var_D <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16)
df$New_A <- c(2,5,5,8,11,14,15,17,20,21,22,23,25,25,27,30)
df$New_B <- c(10,0,0,0,12,12,12,12,0,14,NA_real_,14,16,16,16,16)
df$New_C <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16)
df$New_D <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16)
df


   ID Var_A Var_B Var_C Var_D New_A New_B New_C New_D
1   1     1    10    10    10     2    10    10    10
2   2     3     0    12    12     5     0    12    12
3   3     5     0    14    14     5     0    14    14
4   4     7     0    16    16     8     0    16    16
5   5     9    12    10    10    11    12    10    10
6   6    11    12    12    12    14    12    12    12
7   7    13    12    14    14    15    12    14    14
8   8    15    12    16    16    17    12    16    16
9   9    17     0    10    10    20     0    10    10
10 10    19    14    12    12    21    14    12    12
11 11    21    NA    14    14    22    NA    14    14
12 12    23    14    16    16    23    14    16    16
13 13    25    16    10    10    25    16    10    10
14 14    27    16    12    12    25    16    12    12
15 15    29    16    14    14    27    16    14    14
16 16    31    16    16    16    30    16    16    16][1]][1]

jpeg(filename = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\R\\Images\\Output_A.jpg", quality = 100, width = 1000, height = 1000)
close.screen(all = TRUE) 
my_screen_step1 <- split.screen(c(2, 1))
screen(my_screen_step1[1])
plot(df$Var_A, df$New_A, pch=20 , xlab="Var_A", ylab="New_A", cex=3 , col=rgb(0.4,0.9,0.8,0.5))
my_screen_step2 <- split.screen(c(1, 2), screen = my_screen_step1[2])
screen(my_screen_step2[1])
hist(df$Var_A, border=F , col=rgb(0.2,0.2,0.8,0.7) , main="" , xlab="Var_A", breaks = 30)
screen(my_screen_step2[2])
hist(df$New_A, border=F , col=rgb(0.8,0.2,0.8,0.7) , main="" ,  xlab="New_A", breaks = 30)
dev.off()
```

I have been able to use code to extract the column names needed to automate the process (see below), but I am unsure how to use these lists to create a loop or utilise a function which would automate this process.

```
test_var_names  <- colnames(df %>% select(grep("Var_", colnames(.), value = TRUE)))
test_var_names
new_var_names <- colnames(df %>% select(grep("New_", colnames(.), value = TRUE)))
new_var_names
```

[image: Expected output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code in a function, replacing the constants with a variable.

```
save_plots <- function(data, x, y) {
  file_name <- sub('.*_', '', x)
  jpeg(filename = sprintf('C:\\Users\\Documents\\R\\Images\\Output_%s.jpg', file_name), quality = 100, width = 1000, height = 1000)
  close.screen(all = TRUE) 
  my_screen_step1 <- split.screen(c(2, 1))
  screen(my_screen_step1[1])
  plot(data[[x]], data[[y]], pch=20 , xlab=x, ylab=y, cex=3 , col=rgb(0.4,0.9,0.8,0.5))
  my_screen_step2 <- split.screen(c(1, 2), screen = my_screen_step1[2])
  screen(my_screen_step2[1])
  hist(data[[x]], border=F , col=rgb(0.2,0.2,0.8,0.7) , main="" , xlab=x, breaks = 30)
  screen(my_screen_step2[2])
  hist(data[[y]], border=F , col=rgb(0.8,0.2,0.8,0.7) , main="" ,  xlab=y, breaks = 30)
  dev.off()
}
```

Call the function for each pair of column names using `mapply` :

```
mapply(save_plots, test_var_names, new_var_names, MoreArgs = list(data = df))
```